# Linked-Data-Theater | standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtuoso

While running the `docker-compose up` for git project 
[Linked-Data-Theater](https://github.com/architolk/Linked-Data-Theatre/blob/f12dc18dd7302fbe191b62ac12b379f1f0c642b9/docs/DOCKER.md)
I am getting error `standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory`

Below is a stack trace,

```
ifour.techno@ifour-137 MINGW64 /d/test/Docker/LinkData_Theater_Repo/Linked-Data-Theatre (master)
$ docker-compose up
Starting virtuoso ...
Starting ldt ... done
Attaching to virtuoso, ldt
virtuoso    | standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Server built:          Feb 7 2018 18:52:33 UTC
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Server number:         7.0.85.0
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: OS Name:               Linux
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: OS Version:            4.4.111-boot2docker
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Architecture:          amd64
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
virtuoso exited with code 1
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
ldt         | INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
ldt         | INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.16 using APR version 1.5.2.
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
ldt         | INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
ldt         | INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
ldt         | INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
ldt         | INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
ldt         | INFO: Initialization processed in 890 ms
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
ldt         | INFO: Starting service Catalina
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
ldt         | INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
ldt         | INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ldt         | Mar 01, 2018 7:35:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
ldt         | INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

In this stack trace, you can see that `standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory`

below is my `docker-compose.yml` file,

```
version: '2'

services:
  ldt:
    privileged: true
    container_name: ldt
    image: tomcat:7-jre8
    hostname: ldt.local
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      - ./shared_import:/usr/local/tomcat/temp:z
    networks:
      - ldt

  virtuoso:
    privileged: true
    container_name: virtuoso
    build:
      context: virtuoso
    hostname: virtuoso.local
    ports:
      - "1111:1111"
      - "8890:8890"
    environment:
      DBA_PASSWORD: "dba"
      SPARQL_UPDATE: "true"
      VIRTUOSO_DBA_PWD: dba
    volumes:
      - ./virtuoso_data:/var/lib/virtuoso/db:z
      - ./shared_import:/var/lib/virtuoso/usr/local/tomcat/temp:z
    networks:
      - ldt

networks:
  ldt:
    external:
      name: ldt
```

What is missing? I am a beginner in docker so please help me regarding this problem also give me suggestions. I have googled it but didn't find the problem solution anywhere.

I have also tried the `docker-compose up --build` but getting the same error as above.

Comment: This seems more like [a Linked-Data-Theater issue](https://github.com/architolk/Linked-Data-Theatre/issues) than a docker or Virtuoso question.

Comment: In fact, this looks very much like [Issue #60](https://github.com/architolk/Linked-Data-Theatre/issues/60). Assuming this is a Virtuoso launch issue, please check the `virtuoso.log` which may give more specific info about what file is missing. If nothing there, system logs may reveal the specific and complete command which is failing, and so lead to solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be couple of reasons for the issue you are facing, I resolved the same issue by trying the following:-

1. Ensure all the folders exists, which looks fine in your docker compose
2. Copying some shell script files from windows to unix docker container, ensure you execute dos2unix command after copy. While copying special characters are added which may result in the above issue.

Please add your docker file, its possible issue is in docker file and not in docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable if you use **Windows** as host OS.

Yml file does not allow to pinpoint the exact place of the problem.
The problem seems to be inside your `virtuoso` container. You need to look at the files that this container runs when it starts. Quite likely it has an .sh file that has wrong line endings format. Line endings in the file(s) were converted at some point from Unix format (LF) to Windows format (CR LF).

If such conversion happens to .sh file that will be running inside Docker container, Linux will not recognize Windows format of end of line and will treat the whole file as a single line. It will lead to an error like *standard_init_linux.go:XXX: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"*

**Cause**

The EOL conversion could happen because one of the following:

- your local Git is configured to automatically convert line endings to Windows format (autocrlf = true) when you `git pull` sources
- you saved one of the files in some editor in Windows, so it was saved with `CR LF` line endings

**Solution**

- As a quick fix you can open the file in Notepad++, go to menu `Edit`/`EOL Conversion`/`Unix`, and then save the file
- Another quick fix: use CLI tool `dos2unix` to convert files from command line
- Change git configuration by turning off automatic conversion to Windows EOL format:

> git config --global core.autocrlf input

It will change the setting globally, **for all repositories** on your machine.

You can also set it **per repository**.
See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ for more details.